# Why can't python find my file?

Tags: python, pydub

So someone wrote a joke trapifier script (as in, 'Trap music') and I can't get it to work.

```
usage: trapifier.py [-h] [--samples [SAMPLES]] inputfile outputfile
```

Yet, despite the folder looking like this

```
ls -l
total 14288
-rwxrwxrwx   1 ________  ________  7295612 Mar  2  2008 Chicago.mp3
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 ________  ________     1074 Apr 12 17:00 LICENSE
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 ________  ________     2871 Apr 12 17:00 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 ________  ________        6 Apr 12 17:00 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x@ 48 ________  ________     1632 Apr 12 17:00 samples
-rwxr-xr-x   1 ________  ________     2923 Apr 12 17:00 trapifier.py
```

This command always results in a [Errno 2] No such file or directory

```
./trapifier.py Chicago.mp3 Chiraq.mp3
```

or

```
python trapifier.py Chicago.mp3 Chiraq.mp3
```

or even

```
./trapifier.py /full/path/to/Chicago.mp3 Chiraq.mp3
```

What gives? I feel like there is a rookie mistake somewhere.

The full error message by request:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./trapifier.py", line 89, in <module>
    overlay(parse())
  File "./trapifier.py", line 32, in parse
    base_track = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3(inputfile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 297, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 284, in from_file
    subprocess.call(convertion_command, stderr=open(os.devnull))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in     __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249,     in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Source of the script is hosted at https://github.com/japesinator/trapifier.py

I have all the required libraries (argparse, pydub, os, random).

First Useful Edit: It appears that pydub.AudioSegment failing to load is the culprit. However, things get stranger. In a python terminal I can do

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
```

but I get a no such module error when I do

import pydub.AudioSegment

Comment: Have you explicitly tried a full path to your mp3 file? Like `C:\User\Music\Chicago.mp3`

Comment: What is the actual error message? Bear in mind that likely no one has experience with this particular script, could you dig out the code that actually attempts to load the file?

Comment: What happens with `python trapifier.py ./Chicago.mp3 ./Chiraq.mp3`

Comment: Have you installed the requirements listed in the `requirements.txt` file? If not, you can do that via `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I have already tried full paths, I have all the requirements and nothing different happens when using ./filename

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading the pydub docs but it looks like it needs some external programs (not Python packages) to deal with anything not WAV: https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/#dependencies

Comment: You are correct. I'm installing it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty common that pydub cannot find ffmpeg which is used to decode and encode mp3 files (and all other non-wave formats). If you have ffmpeg installed and it is still not working you can explicitly tell pydub where to find it like so:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "/path/to/ffmpeg"
```

You may also find our [getting ffmpeg set up docs](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#getting-ffmpeg-set-up) helpful =D

edit – **Last resort option**: If you can't get get pydub to find ffmpeg despite your best efforts you could convert everything to wave format before passing the files to pydub. This is a last resort for sure, but it would circumvent the ffmpeg issue since pydub supports wave natively.

Comment: This solution was not working for me so I investigated a bit further and fond [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/62) that now AudioSegment.converter should be used instead of AudioSegment.ffmpeg.